# Dynamically Built Jquery Table Assigning Row Data to Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table built dynamically in my view, I populated a table with values from a jquery popup modal dialog. What i am trying to accomplish is getting each cell in the row and assigning it to variable, at which point I am going to post the data to the database via an ajax call

I am fairly new to JS and jnquery and following many examples, I cant seem to figure out to assign the cell values to the variable, I have included the code below.

Here is the html for the table

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table id="myTest" class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sku Number</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th style="width:300px">Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Border</th>
            <th>Ink Color</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>                
    </table>

    <div style="padding:10px 0; text-align: right; ">
        <input id="submit" type="button" value="Save Order" class="btn btn-warning" style="padding: 10px 20px; margin-right: 15px;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS for populating the table

```
function addItem() {
    var remove = $('<input type="button" id="remove" value="remove" style="width:80px" class="btn btn-danger" />');
    var td = $("<td></td>");
    td.append(remove);
    var valid = true;

    allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

    if (valid) {
        $("#myTest tbody").append(
          "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + skuNumber.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + productName.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + description.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + quantity.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + border.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + inkColor.val() + "</td>" +
          "</tr>");
          dialog.dialog("close");     
          $("#myTest > tbody tr:last").append(td);
          //console.log(td);
    }
    return valid;
}
```

And when you hit the submit button I want to create a list of objects that contains each row in the table, and this is where I am having problems.

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var isAllValid = true;
    var list = [];

    $("#myTest tbody tr td")
        .each(function(index, ele) {
            var orderItem = {
                SkuNumber: skuNumber.val(),
                ProductName: productName.val(),
                Description: description.val(),
                Quantity: quantity.val(),
                Border: border.val(),
                InkColor: inkColor.val()
        };
        list.push(orderItem);
        console.log(orderItem);
    });
```

Comment: What are your **exact** problems? What's not working? What are you expecting vs what is happening?

Comment: nem035 I am trying to get take the text values from my html table for all columns except the button, and add each row to the orderItem list variable, I will then use the list variable in an ajax call to my controller to save the data.. The function is not adding the data for skuNumber, productName, description, quantity, border ot the list, the list is just empty